# How to get ONLY Delete commands issued by SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm troubleshooting an application which sends out dozens of SQL queries per second. I know there's a way to log all SQL statements issued by sqlalchemy using this method:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

But how do I log ONLY `delete` statements ??

Answer (score 0):

You can write [logging filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects):

```
import logging
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class Filter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return 'DELETE' in record.msg

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine').addFilter(Filter())

e = create_engine("sqlite://")
e.execute("CREATE TABLE t(c);")
e.execute("INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES (NULL);")
e.execute("SELECT NULL")
e.execute("DELETE FROM t WHERE c = NULL")
```

Idea was [suggested](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlalchemy/gA3Q4DQWLKw/RNQVHtEREAAJ) by Mike Bayer, the author of SQLAlchemy himself, as a solution to similar problem.

Comment: I just tried this strategy. It's still printing everything.

Comment: @Ahmad In [Configuring Logging](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#configuring-logging) section of SQLAlchemy docs there's this remark: *Therefore, when using Python logging, ensure all echo flags are set to False at all times, to avoid getting duplicate log lines.* Are you sure you don't pass `echo=True` somewhere?